# How to avoid hitting sprinkler lines when aerating lawn or cutting sod?

Tags: damage, sprinkler-system, sod, aeration

Besides pre-marking and avoiding sprinkler heads:

1. Can an aerator dig deep enough to strike the underground sprinkler lines?
2. Can a sod cutter cut under grass deep enough to strike the underground sprinkler lines?

Any other concerns?

Comment: It would depend on how deep the particular sprinkler lines were. I don't think there's a general answer for this, it's going to be specific to how the install was done.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Yeah, have to put trust in the installer that they installed lines deep enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. I've since discovered most sod cutters only dig 2-½" max deep and most aerators only punch 3" max deep. Sprinkler lines in northern states are usually 6" deep.

If someone has a better answer I'm willing to change my accepted answer to yours.